# Can't detect bluetooth devices with bluecove

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I'm trying to show the list of bluetooth devices associated with my PC using bluecove, but it just keep scaning without finding anything, it shows this message on the terminal:

```
BlueCove version 2.1.0 on winsock
```

and stays there without showing any device.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
BluetoothDeviceDiscovery bluetoothDeviceDiscovery=new BluetoothDeviceDiscovery();
        //display local device address and name
        LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        System.out.println("Address: "+localDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
        System.out.println("Name: "+localDevice.getFriendlyName());
        //find devices
        DiscoveryAgent agent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();
```

I think it's a problem in the local device since it's not even showing the adress of the local device.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows 64bit? If so, you may find you need to use BlueCove 2.1.1 SNAPSHOT. Try this here: http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.62/.

Comment: only able to detect pc using BlueCove 2.1.1 SNAPSHOT not able to discover smart phone or BLE device.